# Does unix 'find' give the same order every time?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

If I run `find` (Ubuntu, specifically), can I expect it to give me the same order of results every time? (Assuming, of course, that the actual files haven't changed.)

In other words, if I run

```
$ find foo
```

and it gives me

```
bar.txt
foo.txt
```

can I expect that it will never give me

```
foo.txt
bar.txt
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "probably" but you shouldn't rely on it because any number of things can affect it.

What order do you want the files in?  Decide on that and then use a `find` command (perhaps piped into `sort`) which reproducibly gets the result you need.

Comment: This is a good call. the order doesn't actually matter to me, as long as it's the same; so sorting by anything that won't change (e.g., filename) will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the files is determined by the fine details of the filesystem format and the filesystem driver. You can't rely on it. Depending on the filesystem and operating system, here are things that might change the order:

- A file is created or removed in a traversed directory (even if none of the listed files changed).
- The files are moved around (e.g. transfered to a different filesystem or restored from backup).
- A defragmenter or filesystem check ran and decided to move things around.

If you want a reproducible order, sort the results. `find … | sort` will do nicely if none of the file names contain newlines.